# Django , how to show 'secondary property' of parent in TabularInline

Tags: python, django

I try to do tabular inline admin.

In the child tab, if we include a ForeignKey field, it will show the **str** property of that foreign model.
But how to also show another property of that foreign model?

Here is my models.py

```
class RawMaterial(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ubuy = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    usell = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    uconv = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Coctail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    coctail = models.ForeignKey(Coctail, 
        related_name='ingredient',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rawmaterial = models.ForeignKey(RawMaterial,
        related_name='ingredient',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rawmaterial

    def rawusell(self):
        return self.rawmaterial.usell

    rawusell.short_description = 'UOM'
```

Here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import *

admin.site.register(RawMaterial)

class IngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ingredient
    list_display = ('rawmaterial', 'qty', 'rawusell')

class CoctailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [IngredientInline]

admin.site.register(Coctail, CoctailAdmin)
```

and here what I got
[image: Inline admin]

My question is : How to show rawmaterial.usell in Ingredient tab?

Sincerely

-bino-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the `rawmaterial.usell` field in the ingredient tab but it will not be editable. Since, any field can only be editable if they are a field of that model (Without using any custom form and logic).

So, if you want `rawmaterial.usell` to be editable, you will have to make a `rawmaterial admin`

You can show the `rawmaterial.usell` in `IngredientInline` by doing this.

```py
class IngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ingredient
    readonly_fields = ('rawusell', )
    list_display = ('rawmaterial', 'qty', 'rawusell')

    def rawusell(self, obj):
        return obj.rawmaterial.usell
```

This will start showing `usell` in the inline admin.

Comment: But how if iwant the usell field is auto refreshed when rawmaterial is selected?

Comment: So Django out of the box doesn't support auto-refresh. While you can save the object after selecting any `rawmaterial` and `usell` will be updated with the correct value.